# Why does this python always result True?

Tags: python

no matter what numbers I put in for x or y

even if I change the values of 16 or 250

```
x = anyRandomNumber
y = anyRandomNumber
print ((x + y == 16) == ((10*x) + (25*y) == 250))
```

This was code provided by an instructor in a lesson and it's only suppose to execute true when x = 10 and y = 6

[image]

Comment: What did you expect? Everything is ok!

Comment: `(x + y == 16) and ((10*x) + (25*y) == 250)`?

Comment: False == False is true

Comment: This won't always evaluate to `True`. Check out input `x = 8` and `y = 8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = 1
y = 1
print (x + y == 16)  # False
print ((10*x) + (25*y) == 250) # False
print ((x + y == 16) == ((10*x) + (25*y) == 250)) # False == False

x = 10
y = 6
print (x + y == 16)  # True
print ((10*x) + (25*y) == 250) # True
print ((x + y == 16) == ((10*x) + (25*y) == 250)) # True == True
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put in any random number into your program both sides of the expression evaluate to `False` and thus the overall expression reads `False == False` which is `True`. Some numbers (8 and 8 for example) evaluate `True == False` and thus it outputs `False`

Answer (score 0):

Because False == False is True in python, so when x + y is not 16 and 10x + 25y not equal 250 you have the whole statement evaluate to True. If you want it to work they way you say, then you need to use the 'and' operator ('&' also works):

print ((x + y == 16) and ((10*x) + (25*y) == 250))